# how to play video from byte array in media player

Tags: android, video, byte

i'm using usb device connected to my android device

this device send me a buffer that contain video frame 
it dose that continuously  .

when i receive the buffer i should put specific header into that and write it to sd card as m4v video file .

then i should play it in media player 
so far it works fine but i should show the video live . as soon as usb device send me the buffer i should process it and play it so i can show the video .

my question is how to play a video file from byte buffer without store it in sd card ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is awhile since the question was asked, but I am in the same situation where I have a video transport stream coming through a USB connection.

It looks like you need to create a data source that extends a MediaDataSource and provides the `readAt()` and `getSize()` methods.

My understanding is Android's MediaPlayer, when you supply a URL/URI as a data source (through `setDataSource()`, handles all the networking to download the data or retrieve it from storage, and has its own MediaDataSource the player users.

My plan is to create a service that gets the transport stream from the USB device, and constantly update a custom MediaDataSource that I supply to the MediaPlayer.

[Here](https://github.com/jpxiong/platform_cts/blob/dd40d693dfc3030cf8e9b0bf9f450f2276feb9ca/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/TestMediaDataSource.java) is the only thing I could find on the subject, which was a test written for testing using a MediaDataSource with the MediaPlayer. They read a video from a file into a byte array, and then use that array for the `readAt()` and `getSize()` methods.

Only other resources I could find are people supplying strings to the MediaPlayer, but nothing that involves doing their own networking. Also, I'm curious how a constant stream of video is different that just a fixed sized video.

Edit: I wrote a blog post about MediaDataSource and how to get started with it. Here is the [link](https://medium.com/@jacks205/implementing-your-own-android-mediadatasource-e67adb070731).

Comment: good job ! I need something like this but MediaDataSource was introduced in API level 23(M) which I don't know if 5% of Android users have this yet. Do you have a backwards compatible solution ? I am thinking to make a proxy class or some sort of a cache that streams from the server and then somehow I pass the result to the media player. Yet I don't know how I should make this because mediaplayer only takes URI/path and not bytes/streams

Comment: @PopTudor I think pre-API 23 you may have to look into [Exoplayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) and use that if you want to customize the data source. I've never messed with it, but you can [override the Media Extractor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VjF638VObA) to handle networking and buffering  to try to obtain a backwards compatible solution.

Comment: Thank you. I think that I will go with Exoplayer since it offers so much in comparison with Mediaplayer and on API < 16 I'll just use media player since those are phones that are pretty much going to be extinct in the next 1-2 years so not much is lost there.

Answer (score 0):

I found jacks205 doesn't mention abstract method close() in Closeable. We also need to write the close(), or the compiling will report the following errors:
YourMediaDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method close() in Closeable

Comment: this is supposed to be in the comments section below the answer

Comment: Spirit, yes, I know it, but because my reputation is below 50, so I can't use comment feature here.