# Android MediaPlayer DataSource from my buffer/stream

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I need to be able to initialize MediaPlayer with my memory buffer or stream. The solution provided here: [how to play video from byte array in media player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281145/how-to-play-video-from-byte-array-in-media-player) - to use MediaDataSource with setDataSource works for API level 23 (M) only. Is anybody has suggestion what to do with pre-API23 (L) ?
Since there are setDataSource APis to use FileDescriptor/path/URL/URI I am thinking maybe there is a way to "convert" Stream to URI?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use same mechanism as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343730/mediaplayer-stutters-at-start-of-mp3-playback)
Don't wast your time for ContentProvider, Memoryfile etc.